# RegEx match with lookaheads

Tags: regex

I am been playing with regex and it seems to me. If i can achieve that with regex.

So my test string goes something like this ->

```
1. \"name\":\"asdsaD\"
2. target(name=adsada,    name = asdasd , name=asds dfd ad,cccc=dsaasdas)
```

My desired result is to achieve that matches `\"name\":\"asdsaD\"` , `name=adsada`, `name = asdasd` and `name=asds dfd ad`

My solution that i tried -> `\\*"{0,1}(?:name)\\*"{0,1}\s{0,}[:=]\s{0,}\\*"{0,1}(.*?)([),]|\\*"{0,1})`

https://regex101.com/r/6e58Cb/1

It doesnot match it the way i want it to, tried changing the `.*?` -> `.*`

It matches the whole of second line -> `name=adsada,    name = asdasd , name=asds dfd ad,cccc=dsaasdas)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, a little simpler, and works at least on your given example:

```
name[\\"\:\s=]+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)
```

Basically just finds "name" with an equals, colon, slashes, etc., in front of it, and matches the following word

Comment: looks okay to me but forgot to mention one thing, the last thing might end on comma, close bracket or \\*" or this

Comment: `(name)[\\\"\:\s=]+(.*?)[,)\\\"]+` i think this might work

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a capturing group with a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1` to what is captured to get consistent maches for the backslash and the double quotes on both sides:

```
((?:\\")?)name\1\h*[:=]\h*\1[^:=,]+\1
```

- `((?:\\")?)` Capture group 1, optionally match `\"`
- `name\1\` Match `name` followed by a backrefernce to group 1
- `h*[:=]\h*` Match either `:` or `=` between 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `\1[^:=,]+\1` Match 1+ times any char except `:` `=` and `,` between 2 backreferences

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nno5Q7/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/YOMwDp)

For example

```
String regex = "((?:\\\\\")?)name\\1\\h*[:=]\\h*\\1[^:=,]+\\1";
String string = "1. \\\"name\\\":\\\"asdsaD\\\"\n"
     + "2. target(name=adsada,    name = asdasd , name=asds dfd ad,cccc=dsaasdas)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
\"name\":\"asdsaD\"
name=adsada
name = asdasd 
name=asds dfd ad
```